# Compare Dataframes based on ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes created from a SQL table. I want to find what new rows were added based on new IDs (ID coulmn). Any suggestions?
PS: New to this forum.

````
ID Name Desc
1  A     AA
2  B     BB
3  C     CC

Table 2
ID Name Desc
1  A     AA
2  B     BB
3  C     CC
4  D     DD
5  E     EE

Expected Output
ID Name Desc
4  D    DD
5  E    EE```
````

Answer (score 1):

if you combine the two dataframes then you can remove all rows with duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd
dfA = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'A','AA'],
    [2,'B','BB'],
    [3,'C','CC']
])

dfB = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'A','AA'],
    [2,'B','BB'],
    [3,'C','CC'],
    [4,'D','DD'],
    [5,'E','EE']
])

dfA.append(dfB).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
   0  1   2
3  4  D  DD
4  5  E  EE
```